# WSL VS Code issue- unable to open 'vfprint.c'

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault, printf, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a simple block of code that executes just fine in VS code in my Linux environment. However, in my WSL environment, I get a segmentation fault on printf.
The error reads:

```
Unable to open 'vfprintf.c': Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/stdio-common/vfprintf.c'
(Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/stdio-common/vfprintf.c').
```

I'm not sure why this library would be nonexistent. All of the libraries should be installed, and printf works in other programs on the same system.

For reference, here's the code block that generates the segmentation faults

```c
void countAnimals(){
    int numSheep = 0;
    int numCows = 0;
    while(1){
        if(numSheep >= maxSheep){
            printf("Counted max sheep. Yielding...\n");
            yield();
        }   
        else{
            numSheep = incrementCount(numSheep);
            printf("Counting sheep #%d\n", numSheep);
        } 
        if(numCows >= maxCows){
            printf("Counted max cows. Yielding...\n");
            yield();
        }   
        else{
            numCows = incrementCount(numCows);
            printf("Counting cow #%d\n", numCows);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a machine called `vscode-remote` on your network?  Does it have the given directory (`/wsl+ubuntu/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/stdio-common`) on it?  Does it have the source code for `vfprintf.c` on it?  I suspect the answer to the first question is "No" so the others are superfluous.  Basically, you don't have the source for the library that was compiled, so you won't be able to step through the library functions.

Comment: The answer the the first question is yes. I am using a linux subsystem on windows with remote-WSL. I suppose I don't have the directory containing the source code for vfprint.c which may be the issue- but I'm not sure why it's missing or how to install it

Comment: It's missing because most systems don't provide the source code for the system libraries by default.  If you're lucky, the code is available — Open Source gives you that benefit.  But the code is not installed by default because most people don't need it most of the time (and it can be quite large, and quite confusing, and sometimes there's a lot of patching gone on between the upstream source and the distro building and releasing the code).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh I see. Well that makes sense. I appreciate your response.
Why does it work on my dedicated linux system though? Is that just one of the systems where the source code for the system libraries is provided by default?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As a matter of fact, I do have the source code for printf. Your answer is incorrect and does not explain why it is looking for that particular file when printf exists in a different location

Comment: That's where the source code was when the library was compiled.  That's where the debugger expects to find the source code.  I'm only commenting, not answering, too.  I'm merely trying to help.  If you find that what I'm saying is not helpful, I'm sorry — I'm doing my best to help you when no-one else is.  Good luck!  (I don't have a machine with Windows on it, and therefore I don't have WSL either.  Both reasons I'm commenting, not answering.)  I'll delete my comments if you prefer.

Comment: From testing, this issue normally occurs when trying to print to a non-NULL but invalid pointer location through a linux subsystem, usually due to permission conflicts.

In your case, stdout seems to have been compiled to point to a non-existant console.